# How is the Community user doing reviews?

Tags: discussion, community-user

Looking at the Community user profile, the activity tab shows it reviewing posts. How is this possible? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity

Comment: Deleted user activities get merged into the community user so they are not orphaned.

Comment: This happens more frequently when people improve or override suggested edits than when users are deleted, though.